# eclipse cannot run main "error could not find or load main class"

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using eclipse oxygen. I already had a java project downloaded, in the folder

```
Documents/myJavaProjects/MyProject/
```

I opened eclipse and imported a project. I made the workspace

```
Documents/myJavaProjects
```

I opened the Project /MyProject/

The path to `Main.java` is

```
/MyProject/myPackage/Main.java
```

`Main.java` has this:

```
*/
package myPackage

public class Main {

  /**
   * Makes some sample calls to our Strategy classes.
   * @param args as usual
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
```

When I go to run configurations, the Java Application / Project and Main class does not show up. How come?

Edit: when I try to type in "myProject"/ as the class and `myPackage.Main`, I get `Launching configurring has encountered a problem. Launch configuration references non-existing project MyProject`

Comment: normally there is a soure folder like `src` *inbetween* project and first package folder. Not sure if eclipse supports having the source folder being the same as the project folder (same true for build/output folder). Check the project Properties > Java Build Path > Source (tab)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger How do I check the build path? It says "No actions available" when I go to build path by right clicking my project.

Comment: select the project, open the `Project` menu, choose `Properties`, select `Java Build Path`, click the `Source` tab... **but** if the message is `non-existing project MyProject` then the problem is more like the project was not created at all (with that name)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger after I click `Properties`, there is no option for `Java Build Path`.

Comment: then you didn't create a Java Project... I think....

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I did `open project from file system`.. How do I create a java project?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger When I click `File -> New Java Project` and type in `myProject` it says a project with the name already exists.

Comment: if you created a project that is not a Java Project it sure already exists but cannot be used as Java.... maybe delete the project (without content) and create as Java one )or move the whole project folder from the workspace to a save place, create an empty project and then copy the files back (and refresh the project in eclipse)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I don't want to do that since I clone'd the project from Github. I'd have to create a new directory and go out of the cloned github directory by doing that. Any way to make a project a Java Project? (I'm surprised Eclipse has this issue since so many users use github)

Comment: I the question is missing a lot of information, probably better rewrite/complete it...  more like how to create an java project form a github project, eventually even telling which github project (assuming it is not a private one) {BTW you can copy the `.git` folder together with the cloned folder...} {BTW2 eclipse *should* have support for GIT (it has, I just prefer command line)}

Answer (score -2):

Name your Class exactly as the file.java . End your main class and function with "}"

Comment: My file is `Main.java`. My class is `Main`

Comment: I ended main class with `}`. (just didn't show it in my post)